# Terminal.Gui when leaving charracter are still generated on Linux

Tags: c#, user-interface, .net-5, terminal.gui

I wrote a small Console program using .NET 5 and the [Terminal.Gui library from Miguel de Icaza](https://migueldeicaza.github.io/gui.cs/articles/overview.html).

When I run it on Windows, everything works well. I published it as an autonomous single file for Linux and I run it on an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as a WSL 1 in Windows 10. Once again it works well, but on Linux when I quit the program using `top.Running = false;` the screen is not cleared (not really a problem) but every mouse move create caracters on the console which is more annoying.

[image: Animated gif showing the trouble]

Does anybody solve this trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found the solution on the [GitHub Terminal.Gui project issues][1] I just add `Application.Shutdown();` to my main. So It becomes :

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
  int rc = 0;
  try
  {
    Application.Run<AppGui>();
    Application.Shutdown();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    rc = -1;
  }

  if (rc > 0)
    return AppGui.rc;
  else
    return rc;
}
```

The `Application.Driver.End()` proposed do not solve completely the problem there were still garbages when I click on the mouse buttons (right click past was no longer working).
[1]: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs/issues/281